# Text in 3 columns HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a one column layout on my webpage im currently building.

But in that one column I want 3 columns on text right next to each other.

```
Page:
------------------------------------------------

Col 1         Col 2        Col 3
--------   -----------   -----------
--------   -----------   -----------
--------   -----------   -----------
--------   -----------   -----------
--------   -----------   -----------
--------   -----------   -----------

------------------------------------------------
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: There is [a CSS draft for this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). Maybe modern browsers already support this.

Comment: IE doesn’t yet, and Opera only got support recently, but Firefox and Safari have had it for a while: http://caniuse.com/#search=columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a CSS grid system.

Examples are http://cssgrid.net/ or others like http://960.gs, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), [Blueprint CSS](http://blueprintcss.org/).. take your pick.

You can learn how to work with a grid rather quickly, and it will help you imensely in keeping your layout clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [CSS3's multi column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). But it'll only work in modern browsers and with vendor prefixes:

```
#iwantcolumns {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Another way would be to use JavaScript. E.g. jQuery with [columnizer plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/):

```
$('#mydiv').columnize();
$('#myotherdiv').columnize({ width: 200 });
$('#mythirddiv').columnize({ columns: 2 });
```